# Realm database layer gives error under Eclipse, Genymotion emulator and devices

Tags: android, genymotion, eclipse-adt, realm

I installed on to Eclipse ADT Realm DB (version 0.79.1) (http://realm.io/docs/java/0.79.0/) and Genymotion emulator (https://www.genymotion.com/#!/download).

I've done every step of the installation.

I've used Genymotion for a long time so that is fine.

I've installed Realm DB and I've tried to run a example project that I've found in the zip that I've downloaded, but it gives me this error:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/example.db-1/base.apk"], nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]] coudn't find "libtighdb-jni.so"
```

It give me error on Genymotion, HTC One M7 and Nexus 7 2012, both 32 bit architecture.

The SDK Emulators do not work for me at all.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks and happy coding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is in this thread

https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/705#issuecomment-77466953

Best regards.